# How to disable any specific cronjob in magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2, cron, magento2.3.4

Sometimes indexing cron process went away and a similar thing happens for the consumers_runner and yotpo_yotpo_orders_sync cron job so I want to disable the consumers_runner and yotpo_yotpo_orders_sync cron job.

Answer (score 4):

After reading the Magento Dev Documentation, I found a below solution:

Cron jobs do not have a disable feature as we have for observers. However, a Cron job can be disabled by using the following technique: **schedule a time that contains a date that will never happen** like `0 0 30 2 *` which means `At 00:00 on day-of-month 30 in February`.

The detailed explanation is given here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-ref.html#disable-cron-job

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Disable Cron Job in Magento 2**

To disable the cron job in Magento 2 you have to first create your module and rewrite the same cron job in your module’s `crontab.xml` file.

Let’s say I want to disable the cron job called `notify_me` which is defined in the `Orange_Notify` module. To disable this cron job create `crontab.xml` file under your custom module and change the schedule value to `0 0 30 2 *`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <job name="notify_me" instance="Orange\Notify\Model\Notify" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 0 30 2 *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

By doing this we are telling Magento to run `notify_me` cron job at 00:00 on the 30th of February – at the date which will never happen. That means this cron job will never run.

Comment: How does Magento know that _our_ schedule is the right one and not the one from the `Orange_Notify` module?

Comment: @bfontaine Because your custom module has that module in sequence in the /etc/module.xml

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be better to create a patch.

In the *composer.json* file:

```
"extra": {
    "patches": {
        "yotpo/magento2-module-yotpo-reviews": {
            "Stop the Yotpo cron": "patches/yotpo-cron-stop.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

then create your patch file: *<mage_dir>/patches/yotpo-cron-stop.patch* using

```
<schedule>0 0 30 2 *</schedule>
```