# Magento2 stop giftcart code pool auto generation

Tags: magento2, gift-card

Magento2 How to stop the auto code pool generation in following table?

**magento_giftcardaccount_pool**

I am importing custom code. I want to stop auto generation

Answer (score 0):

Disable the cron `magento_giftcardaccount_generage_codes_pool`.

See here on how to disable a cron job:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/321897/7790

You may also need to create an around plugin for \Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\Pool::generatePool to ensure that it never runs. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#around-methods. Make sure you do not call callable $proceed to prevent the generatePool from executing.